# Paging file reset - Windows 7

Tags: paging

We know that the paging file will be reset every restart/shutdown.

Is there anyway to reset the paging file without restart or shutdown?

And does it really matter if I left the paging file in a very small size such as 200MB as it warned me that I won't be able to read the dump file that will lead me to know the problem in case of BSOD.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/418683/clear-page-file-without-reboot-on-windows-server-2003

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. The paging file is in use by many processes and the OS itself (for the paged pool, among other things). You can't zero it without crashing every process that's using it.

Dump files might not matter to you, but "out of memory" errors probably will. There are dozens of questions here from people complaining that they have plenty of free RAM but they're still seeing "out of memory" messages. The reason is that they have removed their page file or set it to some absurdly small size. You are almost always better off leaving the page file alone.